# How to create a live streaming application?

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, webrtc, real-time, live-streaming

I am working on an application which requires live video streaming feature. Just like Facebook, where a user can broadcast video to audience in real time. Basically, I need to know what are tools and technologies involved to develop a streaming application.

I have gone through some articles over internet but was not able to fully understand the concepts of streaming and as a result I still don't know from where to start.
Till now this is what I understood:

1. The client(mobile/desktop/laptop) will record the video and the application will send media file in form of packets to server.
   **Ques: How will my application break the video in packets? (Sorry, if this sound too broad or silly but I need to know from where to start?)**
2. The Streaming server. I got that it will be responsible for handling the packets.
   **Ques: How to build a streaming server? How and what actions will it perform? I see there are some paid tools which provide streaming server services like [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/). Do I need one of them or will it be worth to build own server(considering application will be in nascent stage)?**
3. Broadcasting content to audience in real time
   **Ques: Will I need to use [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) or similar technology to achieve this?**

May be I oversimplified it but this is what I got till now and any help to even get me started will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: @szatmary Sorry, for too many ques on post but they all points to one ques- How do I get started or develop a video streaming application?

Comment: 1) rtmp, 2) nginx-rtmp, ffmpeg, hls 3) hls.js. <= these are the technologies/programs you need to understand.